# PHP Session variables in multiple pages

Tags: php, session

So, here I have page1.php:

```
<form action="action_form.php" method="post">
<select name="font_syle">
<option value="tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="arial">Arial</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

Here action_form.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$font_style = $_POST["font_syle"];
$_SESSION["font_syle"] = $font_style;
if($_SESSION["font_syle"] == 'tahoma') $font_style = 10;
else if($_SESSION["font_syle"] == 'arial') $font_style = 20;

$total = $font_style;

echo $total;
?>
```

And here page.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
include 'action_form.php';
ob_end_clean();

echo $total;
?>
```

I don't know why the value of "$total" is not printed on page.php

Comment: Do you post the `font_syle` param in `page.php?`?

Comment: so you want to print the $font_style in second page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

page.php includes `action_form.php`. That sets the value of `$font_style` to:

```
$font_style = $_POST["font_syle"];
```

Since page.php hasn't just been posted through a form, it's setting `$font_style` to an empty string. So when you come to echo it out, there's nothing there to echo.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just reference the $_SESSION variable directly

Comment: Add the end of `action_form.php`, add a line `$_SESSION['font_size'] = $font_style;`. Then you can print it on other pages with `echo $_SESSION['font_size'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `echo $_SESSION["font_syle"];` in the page.php to print it

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your form is going to `action_form.php` and store the data inside the variable `$_SESSION`.

When you open `page.php` the data doesn't exist anymore because `$total` does not move between page.

The solution here is to change :

```
<form action="action_form.php" method="post">
```

for

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
```

OR

Print out the session variable instead.

Comment: I want to use the result of the form in multiple pages.

Comment: @user1689166 Then store this either inside a database or inside the array `$_SESSION` and on every page call `session_start()` on the first line.

Comment: How can I make "$total" to be inside the $_SESSION?

Comment: @user1689166: Google can help here sometimes. $_SESSION is an array so treat it as such, e.g. $_SESSION['foo'] = "bar". http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php